# How to ask properly: "how grave a mistake is"?

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests, questions

I Googled the following sentence:

[“how serious is the mistake”](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22how+serious+is+the+mistake%22&btnK=Google+Search) and it produced only 5 hits! Does it mean the sentence is ungrammatical? I then tried Googling [“how serious is the error”](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22how+serious+is+the+error%22&start=20) and only got 27 hits. Is that ungrammatical too? What mistake am I making?

How do I reformulate my question, in order to make it correct?

Comment: Interesting.  I google it and get a page saying "about 4 results" but displaying 10 results.  But what are you looking for?  Without quotes, I get 150 million hits.  How about `"how serious" mistake`?  That reports 375,000 results for me.

Comment: With "how serious is the error" and "how serious is the problem", there are respectively 24,000 and 75,000 hits.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about google search, not about English.

Comment: The google search seems to be the OP's attempt at research. The main question is how to ask "how grave a mistake is".

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Depending on the context, your wording, "How serious is the mistake?" is fine.

Comment: [How serious is this mistake](https://www.google.it/search?q=how+serious+is+the+mistake&oq=how+serious+is+the+mistake&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22how+serious+is+this+mistake%22) 27 results. Not much of an improvement! The only way I can explain it, is to say if something is a mistake, it's a mistake, regardless of its level of seriousness. But the low count of Google's results  is very curious indeed.

Comment: @Graffito look at the number of hits on that search, ["how serious is the error?"](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22how+serious+is+the+error%22&start=20) produces ONLY 27 hits And on Google Books only 16 hits https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22how+serious+is+the+error%22&tbm=bks&start=20

Comment: On the other hand, ["how serious is the problem"](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22how+serious+is+the+problem%22&start=80) gets  77,300 hits. How curious!

Comment: @Mari-LouA - ["how serious is the error"](https://www.google.fr/search?q=how+serious+is+the+error&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=nGvwVsycC8yua-L4rpAO#q=%22how+serious+is+the+error%22) produces 24400 results. *Surprising*! Same issue on google books with 238 hits. For a mistake, "grave" would be more appropriate than "serious".

Comment: @Graffito no, it doesn't. Scroll and click on the page numbers at the bottom. This is Google, it gives an estimate and then the real results are quite, very different. It's not the first time I have seen this phenomenon. I've been fooled by Google results on more than one occasion.

Comment: @Mari-LouA -  You are right, I have been cheated! Curiously, "how serious is *this* error" shows 2860 hits.

Answer (score 2):

**There is nothing wrong with the question "How serious is the mistake?".**

I'm not sure why the hit count is so low. Google searches for multi-word phrases are often much lower than for strings of words. "How serious is the" gets many more, showing that the sentence is very valid while other nouns are following, so there is no grammatical issue.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected that it is a lexical rather than grammatical issue. Would you say, for example,  "How serious is the fallacy?"

Comment: I think you could and would ask "How serious is the.." about anything that could have different degrees of seriousness.Mistakes can be more or less serious, and probably so could fallacies.